# Macos Ventura 13.5 SSL_ERROR_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ALERT or net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: macos, ssl, xmlhttprequest, macos-ventura

I have installed VPN Avanti Secure for my job stuff. It work fine in major case. But there particular case when i need to use local servise inside my vpn network. It's website with AJAX and the problem is that i can go to this website and for example find some user, but can't to see hes information. For some reson the browser permit me do sum initial stuff like find user and then it block my network request for example when i want to expand user information.

[Request 200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHLUe.png)

The first POST's of interactions is going well. But after it's like i can't send any more the request. And this column is empty.

[Request doesn't start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtioO.png)

This problem occurs only on my MacBook with Ventura 13.5. On other MacBook with 13.1 or windows os it works fine.

I tried import valid certificate from other pc for this web page, but nothing.

I think the problem is in some updates between 13.1 and 13.5 and I want to understand what I can downgrade to fix the bug.

1. Obviously clear cache and launch in incognito mode
2. Export a certificate from working pc end  import to my
3. Flush dns on mac

All typical recommendation from internet